# Deprecation warning when using Cucumber with Rails 3.1: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated

Tags: cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3.1, deprecated

This is a fresh project setup on Rails 3.1. When I run **cucumber features** I always get the same annoying deprecation warning twice. Any guidance would be appreciated.

> DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from require at /Users/Mandingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cucumber-rails guys are working on it as we talk :)
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/issues/169